# c# don't read SOME code in a specific button

Tags: c#

I am learning about buttons and I wrote the instruction of printing 'Hey World' when pressing a button and down below I literally wrote the same instruction again and only prints the first one. I tried with `MessageBox` and it doesn't work. I put another button and copied both instructions of printing hey world and it worked, but in the first button still, doesn't catch that instruction. What could be wrong?

```
private void btn_heyworld(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey world");
    Console.WriteLine("Hey World 2");
}
```

And it prints only ... Hey world

Comment: This can´t be your actual code because that one you posted will *definitly* print both statements, Your question is thus unsolvable.

Comment: maybe you didn't rebuild? or didn't save and run the previous version of your app w/ only one statement

Comment: It must work...If it is not, then you must have made some mistake when defining an event for this button. Maybe you have some other `ButtonClick` event handler assigned which prints only first line?

Comment: Do you have a second event handler that the Button is subscribed to rather than the one above?

Comment: Change the text of the first `Console.WriteLine()` so you can verify that you are running the code you think you are running.

Comment: why don't you `try{} catch{}` the exception on skipping line?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the start of the method. Click the button, see if it hits your breakpoint. You can do this by selecting the first line the method and hitting F9

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several scenarios where you'd get the described behaviour but none with the code you have. Using something like a `MessageBox` instead of `Console.WriteLine` won't change the behaviour.

A few likely scenarios

1. **You don't see anything** - this would suggest that your code isn't being called, maybe you've got a typo in the name of something? Note many such cases would result in an error because you'd be trying to call a method that doesn't exist - e.g. if you're calling `SayHello2` instead of `SayHello` by mistake and `SayHello2` doesn't exist you'd get an error.
2. **You only see one of the messages** - this might suggest that you're overwriting something before showing it or only calling part of your code.

For example, you set `msg` to "Hey world" but overwrite it with "Hey world 2" and then write `msg` to the `Console` - `msg` now says "Hey world 2" so that's what will be written. Something like this

```
private void btn_heyworld(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = "Hey world";
    msg = "Hey world 2";
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Another case might involve you having multiple handlers like this

```
private void btn_heyworld(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey world");
}

private void btn_heyworld2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey World 2");
}
```

If your button is linked to `btn_heyworld` you'll only get the `btn_heyworld` behaviour.

3. **You get both messages** - this would suggest that your button is tied to the correct handler and is doing what is expected - i.e. running when clicked and printing your messages.

Suggestions

1. Try the code you've posted in your question and make sure that your button's handler is called `btn_heyworld`.
2. Try the code I've included and look for the behaviour I've described.
3. Post your actual code so we can get a better handle on what you're actually doing.